# How to achieve thread-safety in bidirectional tables using just 4 bits per entry, while avoiding any global locks?

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, thread-safety, lookup-tables

I'm having trouble creating a safe and efficient locking mechanism for a particular problem. Here's an oversimplified version of the situation.

I have two tables called A and B, each of which contains space for (say) 10 entries. Of these 10 entries, 9 of them are pointers into the other table, and the remaining entry is NULL. At program start, the non-NULL entries start off in bijective correspondence. For example, if I follow a link from table A to table B and then back again, I arrive at my original location in A. Similarly, if I follow a link from table B to table A and then back again, I arrive at my original location in B. There's global variables for tracking the location of the NULL values.

After setting up this bijective correspondence, the program spawns two threads. The first thread ("Thread A") repeatedly does the following: it chooses an entry of A at random, swaps it into the NULL spot, and then proceeds to adjust the corresponding pointer in B in order to maintain the bijective correspondence. The other thread ("Thread B") does exactly the same thing, but starting with the other table. So it randomly chooses entries in B, swaps them into the NULL spot, and adjusts the corresponding pointer in A.

> **Question:** How can we make this system thread-safe without locking the entire table, preferably using just the bottom 4 bits of each pointer?

Obviously, the actual situation I care about involves a much bigger tables, plus there'll be a (small amount) of data attached to each entry. Also, in the real thing, the movements aren't completely random; they serve a purpose. Feel free to ask if you want more details about what I'm actually trying to do, though I don't think these details are too relevant to solving the actual multithreading problem.

**Addendum.** I've just noticed that there's multiple versions of this problem. The easiest version of this says that if we pick an entry and realize it can't be moved, that's perfectly OK - we just randomly pick another entry and move that instead. The medium-difficulty version says that we're allowed to do this for A only. Meaning that in table B, we have to block and wait until movement is possible, and cannot simply choose another entry instead. That hardest version of this problem says that we're denied the right to simply give up and rerandomize for both tables. FWIW, I'm interested in all versions of the problem; thus, even if you can just solve the "easy" version, I would still value your answer.

**Addendum 2.** Here's some example code targeting x86-64/Linux, albeit without any thread safety mechanisms. The current design gives just 3 bits per pointer due to the way qwords are packed, but we can upgrade this to 4 bits if needed by using 128-bit entries instead.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Clear the bottom 3 bits of a 64-bit value
#define GET_POINTER(val) (uint64_t*) ((val) & ~0x7ULL)

// Concatenates the top 61 bits of new_ptr with the bottom 3 bits of old_val
// so long as the bottom 3 bits of new_ptr are 0's
#define MODIFY_VALUE(new_ptr, old_val) ((uint64_t) (new_ptr)) ^ ((old_val) & 0x7ULL) 

// Declare globals
uint64_t A[10], B[10];
int index_of_NULL_value_A, index_of_NULL_value_B;

// Initialize tables
void init_globals() {

    // Initialize A[0] and B[0] to NULL pointers
    A[0] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0;
    B[0] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0;

    // Record the initial indexes of the NULL values
    index_of_NULL_value_A = 0;
    index_of_NULL_value_B = 0;

    // Create pointers from A to B
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        A[i] = (uint64_t) &B[i];
    }

    // Create pointers from B to A
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        B[i] = (uint64_t) &A[i];
    }

}

void verify_integrity_of_table(uint64_t* A, int index_of_NULL_value_A) {

    // Verify the forward direction
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

        if (i == index_of_NULL_value_A) {

            // Check that the NULL value is at this spot
            if (A[i] != (uint64_t) NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integrity check A failed! Missing NULL at i: %d\n", i);
                exit(1);
            }

        } else {

            // Check link integrity
            if (&A[i] != GET_POINTER(*GET_POINTER(A[i]))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integrity check A failed! Dodgy link at i: %d\n", i);
                exit(1);
            }

        }

    }

}

void verify_integrity() {

    // Verify the forward direction
    verify_integrity_of_table(A, index_of_NULL_value_A);

    // Verify the backward direction
    verify_integrity_of_table(B, index_of_NULL_value_B);

}

typedef void *(*start_routine_t)(void *);
pthread_t pthread_create_or_exit(start_routine_t start_routine) {

    // Declare variables
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int result;

    // Create the thread
    result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, start_routine, NULL);
    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Failed to create thread!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Return the thread id
    return thread_id;

}

void do_a_random_swap(uint64_t* A, int* addr_of_index_of_NULL_value) {
    
    // Get the index of the NULL value
    int index_of_NULL = *addr_of_index_of_NULL_value;

    // Choose a random index
    int i = rand() % 10;
    while (i == index_of_NULL) {
        i = rand() % 10;
    }

    // Update the backpointer
    uint64_t* new_ptr = &A[index_of_NULL];
    uint64_t  old_val = *(GET_POINTER(A[i]));
    *GET_POINTER(A[i]) = MODIFY_VALUE(new_ptr, old_val);

    // Copy the item into the NULL spot and clear the old spot
    A[index_of_NULL] = A[i];
    A[i] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0

    // Update the NULL index tracker
    *addr_of_index_of_NULL_value = i;

}

void* fst_start_routine(void* arg) {

    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 0) {
            do_a_random_swap(A, &index_of_NULL_value_A);
        } else {
            sleep(0.1);
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

void* snd_start_routine(void* arg) {
    
    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 0) {
            do_a_random_swap(B, &index_of_NULL_value_B);
        } else {
            sleep(0.1);
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

void* integrity_checker_start_routine(void* arg) {

    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever, checking the integrity of the system during odd seconds
    for (;; sleep(0.1)) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 1) {
            verify_integrity();
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

int main() {

    // Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Initialize table and NULL-index trackers
    init_globals();

    // Verify integrity of the initialized values
    verify_integrity();

    // Spawn some threads
    pthread_create_or_exit(fst_start_routine);
    pthread_create_or_exit(snd_start_routine);
    pthread_create_or_exit(integrity_checker_start_routine);

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    // Return successfully (we never get here)
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are these two threads the only ones interacting with the tables or are there other readers?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, to keep the problem from getting too hard, let's assume that there's just two threads. Of course, if you can solve the harder version of this problem in which multiple threads might already be reading some of the objects, post away!

Comment: Just use per-entry lock in both tables (you may implement such lock using 1 bit of the entry). You need also to somehow avoid deadlocks because of acquiring same pair of locks in two threads but in different order. E.g., after both threads acquire one lock but found the other lock to be already owned by other, one of threads could give up and release its own lock.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yeah that's the gist, but the details seem non-trivial. I guess we can use a specific bit position (e.g. LSB) to indicate that the current entry is going to be moved, and another bit position (e.g. 2ndLSB) to indicate that the linked entry is going to be moved. How to actually use this to create a fast and 100% reliable mechanism is quite unclear to me, however.

Comment: Your whole problem is quite big for Stack Overflow format. How "fast" a method would be, it depends on the programming language you use, but you don't specify the one. Also, in case of concurrent mechanisms their efficiency greatly depends on **actual** workflow, not on the "toy" one.

Comment: One standard way to avoid deadlocks when locking pairs is to lock in order of increasing address.  (If you find the second one already locked, IIRC you can spin-wait for it without unlocking the first, since the increasing-order rule makes a cycle impossible.) 
 I haven't grokked this problem but it sounds like you're considering something more than just a 1-bit spinlock per entry, so it might not be that simple.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I'm targeting x86-64/Linux. The actual workflow is a bit complicated (but I'll happily explain it), and I'll be happy with a solution that works for the toy problem, since at least that will get me started thinking in the right direction. The actual workflow is this...

Comment: ... Instead of Table A, there's a giant lookup table of key-value pairs that uses something a bit like cuckoo hashing, with some differences that are hard to explain in a short comment. Instead of Table B, there's a slab allocator. Each block in the slab allocator has a backpointer to the lookup table. The catch is that sometimes the entries in the lookup table need to be moved (because that's how cuckoo hashing works), and sometimes blocks in the slab allocator need to be moved (to defragment the slabs and help free up memory). In the real-life problem, there's multiple threads...

Comment: ... doing all these things in complex patterns. But I'd be quite happy to see just a tiny slice of this problem solved, namely the problem of maintaining bidirectional relationships when two threads are involved. I just want to see what kinds of solutions people are using for these problems, as that will get me started thinking in the right direction. Unfortunately, right now I'm actually just at a complete loss for how to begin to get started, in part due to my lack of experience with multithreading.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've updated the question to include some example code. Happy to use spinlocks, either by disabling interrupts, or by just pretending that interrupts aren't a problem for the time being. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to use (any) of the main locking mechanisms to solve the problem.

Comment: x86-64 has `lock bts` to atomically test-and-set a bit without disturbing other bits.  Other ISAs can do something like `atomic_fetch_or` or `atomic_compare_exchange_weak`.  Disabling interrupts wouldn't help on a multi-core system, only against other threads that might run on *this* core!  Anyway, suffice it to say that using a single bit of an `_Atomic uint64_t` as a spinlock is a non-problem in C11, if we can find a way to use that building block.

Comment: `(val) & ~0x4` doesn't clear the low 3 bits, it clears only the 3rd bit, the one bit set in `0x4`.  It manages to avoid clearing any of the high 32 bits thanks to sign-extension when the `int` value `~0x4` = `-5` is sign-extended to 64-bit.  To clear the low 3 bits, use `val & -8ULL`

Comment: Don't have time to write a whole answer right now, but I think @Tsyvarev has the right approach? If you acquire rw locks for all four entries affected by the swap before executing it, then the program should be thread safe. If any of the locks are held, give up and throw an error, releasing any locks acquired so far (or do something else; the choice for handling this situation will depend on your expectations for the workload - see "optimistic concurrency control" as a topic for more on this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking primitives in high level languages do not function. https://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/65 You must use standard library functions that provide locking or interlocked/atomic functionality if available, or if you can't synthesize one from standard library functions you need to break out assembly.

Assuming you're not running in some weird embedded environment, it can be done with the _Atomic methods.

If I have the following assembly functions I can do it:

perform_swap_a would look like this:

```
struct table_entry {
   _Atomic struct table_entry *ptr;
   void *attached;
}

const uintptr_t bitmask = ~3ULL;

void perform_swap_a(size_t index)
{
   // Lock our side
   uintptr_t selected;
   _Atomic struct table_entry *expected;
   do {
      selected = (uintptr_t)atomic_load_explicit(&A[index].ptr,memory_order_acquire);
      expected = (struct table_entry *)(selected & bitmask);
      // Spin until we locked this one
   } while (atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&A[index].ptr, &expected, (struct table_entry *)((selected & bitmask) + 1));
   // Lock other side
   struct table_entry *bptr = ((struct table_entry *)((uintptr_t)atomic_load_explicit(&A[index].ptr,memory_order_acquire) ~3);
   do {
      selected = (uintptr_t)atomic_load_explicit(&bptr->ptr,memory_order_acquire);
      expected = (struct table_entry *)(selected & bitmask);
      // Spin until we locked this one
   } while (atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&bptr->ptr, &expected, (struct table_entry *)((selected & bitmask) + 1)); 
   // Perform swap
   struct table_entry newentry;
   newentry = A[index];
   A[index_of_NULL_value_A] = A[index]
   A[index] = newentry;
   size_t tmp = index;
   index = index_of_NULL_value_A;
   index_of_NULL_value_A = tmp;
   // Unlock other side
   atomic_store_explicit(&bptr->ptr,(struct table_entry *)((uintptr_t)bptr->ptr & bitmask),  memory_order_release);
   bptr->ptr = (table_entry *)(read_ptr(bptr) & bitmask);
   // Unlock our side
   atomic_store_explicit(&A[index]->ptr, (struct table_entry *)((uintptr_t)bptr->ptr & bitmask),  memory_order_release);
}
```

perform_swap_b is similar:

```
void perform_swap_b(size_t index)
{
   // Lock other side
   struct table_entry *aptr;
   uintptr_t selected;
   struct table_entry * expected;
   do {
      // Every time we go around this loop, the pointer in index can change so we must reload.
      aptr = atomic_load_explicit(&B[index].ptr,memory_order_acquire);
      selected = atomic_load_explicit(&aptr->ptr,memory_order_acquire);
      expected = (struct table_entry *)(selected & bitmask);
      // Spin until we locked this one
   } while (aptr == NULL ||
        atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&aptr->ptr, &expected, (struct table_entry *)((selected & bitmask) + 1));
   // Lock our side
   do {
       selected = atomic_load_explicit(&B[index].ptr,memory_order_acquire);
      expected = (struct table_entry *)(selected & bitmask);
      // Spin until we locked this one
   } while (atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&B[index]->ptr, &expected, (struct table_entry *)((selected & bitmask) + 1));
   // Perform swap
   struct table_entry newentry;
   newentry = B[index];
   B[index_of_NULL_value_A] = B[index]
   B[index] = newentry;
   size_t tmp = index;
   index = index_of_NULL_value_B;
   index_of_NULL_value_B = tmp;
   // Unlock our side
   atomic_store_explicit(&B[index]->ptr, (struct table_entry *)((uintptr_t)B[index]->ptr & bitmask), memory_order_release);
   // Unlock other side
   atomic_store_explicit(&aptr->ptr, (struct table_entry *)((uintptr_t)(aptr->ptr) & bitmask);
}
```

The whole algorithm only used 1 bit in the pointer so that constant 3 can be changed to a 1 if need be.

Comment: Those special functions you need are available in C11 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).  Just change the first struct member to `_Atomic table_entry *ptr;`, and use `atomic_load_explicit( &A[index].ptr, memory_order_acquire )`.  (Actually can be `relaxed` because you're just using it an input to CAS; the `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` needs to be `acquire`).  Or better, just `while ( atomic_fetch_or_explicit( &A[index].ptr, memory_order_acquire) & 3 != 0 ) { }` (or with _mm_pause() and  check read-only before retry in the spin-wait loop.

Comment: And to unlock, you need at least `release`: `atomic_store_explicit( &B[index].ptr, memory_order_release)`.  (The default for `_Atomic` is `seq_cst`, but your current code using special functions to do atomic ops on plain objects is buggy, at best it's like a `relaxed` atomic store which might not make the updated value of `attached` visible to readers that see the unlock.  If you do want to avoid using `_Atomic` on the member, the special functions to do atomic ops on plain `uint64_t` are GNU C `__atomic_store_n` etc. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oh, we do have C versions of these now. Always nice to learn something new. I only knew about the C++ versions.

Comment: If you knew about the C++ versions, why would you write something silly like "*Locking primitives in high level languages do not function.*".  `volatile` in C and C++ doesn't give you sequential consistency, and until C++11 / C11 there weren't portable atomic RMWs either.  But those are only two high-level languages. Java `volatile` does give sequential consistency allowing Dekker's algorithm, and has had a portable AtomicInteger since before 2011 I think. Probably it wasn't the only high-level language.  Anyway, that 2008 blog article hardly reflects the state of high-level languages in 2023

Comment: @PeterCordes: And C# has a working lock statement and a library with things like InterlockedIncrement. But you can't implement any of these yourself without busting out assembly. I have just now repeated his Dekker test in Java (by porting that C code over to java), and it does not work.

Comment: That's odd, did that blog not implement Dekker's algorithm correctly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm)?  Java `volatile` is supposed to give sequential consistency, so `volatile int flag1, flag2, turn;` should do it if both threads are referencing the same shared variables.  (Making `gSharedCounter` volatile is silly; the point of a mutex algorithm is to protect plain variables.) As for C#, yeah most languages expose lock-free atomic load/store/RMW via library functions; C++ is no different.  You can't implement `std::atomic<>` without asm or GNU C `__atomic` builtins or w/e

Comment: The blog article's code sets `turn` *before* spin-waiting to enter the critical section.  The wikipedia version sets it after leaving.  I haven't tried to work through the possibilities to see if there's a correctness problem even with `_Atomic int` in C (which would also give sequential consistency.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I thought of that; but I didn't want to completely discard his work; namely if it's an algorithmic problem it would show on a hyper threading processor which he reports it does not. But since you brought it up; I moved assignment of turn down to where Wikipedia has it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the blog's dekker.c on my system (i7-6700k).  As expected, with `volatile` it had some missed counts when run as `./a.out 10000000`.  Changing the first thee variables from `volatile` to `_Atomic` made it work (tried multiple times, and with an arg of 1 billion), literally no other changes needed.  (`_Atomic` is a keyword; `stdatomic.h` is only needed for functions.  I left gSharedCounter as volatile.)  IDK why a Java port of it wouldn't work since apparently this version of the algorithm works.

Comment: So what's the conclusion about Dekker's algorithm? Is it OK so long as _Atomic is used in the appropriate spots?

Comment: @SocraticMathTutor: The test harness is good. Try it and see for yourself. I'm not going to trust it on the very next processor architecture until I've tried it on that architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a locking mechanism going by following this comment: "If any of the locks are held, give up and throw an error, releasing any locks acquired so far." Long story short, the code below treats the bottommost bit of the first pointer you encounter as a spinlock, and the bottommost bit of the second pointer as a try-and-give-up-on-everything lock. If you can acquire both locks, you can move the entry safely.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

// Clear the bottom 3 bits of a 64-bit value
#define GET_POINTER(val) (uint64_t*) ((val) & ~0x7ULL)

// Concatenates the top 61 bits of new_ptr with the bottom 3 bits of old_val
// so long as the bottom 3 bits of new_ptr are 0's
#define MODIFY_VALUE(new_ptr, old_val) ((uint64_t) (new_ptr)) ^ ((old_val) & 0x7ULL)

// Declare globals
uint64_t A[10], B[10];
int index_of_NULL_value_A, index_of_NULL_value_B;

// Initialize tables
void init_globals() {

    // Initialize A[0] and B[0] to NULL pointers
    A[0] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0;
    B[0] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0;

    // Record the initial indexes of the NULL values
    index_of_NULL_value_A = 0;
    index_of_NULL_value_B = 0;

    // Create pointers from A to B
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        A[i] = (uint64_t) &B[i];
    }

    // Create pointers from B to A
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        B[i] = (uint64_t) &A[i];
    }

}

void verify_integrity_of_table(uint64_t* table, int index_of_NULL_value) {

    // Verify the forward direction
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

        if (i == index_of_NULL_value) {

            // Check that the NULL value is at this spot
            if (table[i] != (uint64_t) NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integrity check failed! Table: %p, Missing NULL at i: %d\n", (void*) table, i);
                exit(1);
            }

        } else {

            // Lock is zero
            if (table[i] != (uint64_t) GET_POINTER(table[i])) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integrity check failed! Table: %p, Locked object at i: %d\n", (void*) table, i);
                exit(1);
            }

            // Check link integrity
            if (&table[i] != GET_POINTER(*GET_POINTER(table[i]))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integrity check failed! Table: %p, Dodgy link at i: %d\n", (void*) table, i);
                exit(1);
            }

        }

    }

}

void verify_integrity() {

    // Verify the forward direction
    verify_integrity_of_table(A, index_of_NULL_value_A);

    // Verify the backward direction
    verify_integrity_of_table(B, index_of_NULL_value_B);

}

typedef void *(*start_routine_t)(void *);
pthread_t pthread_create_or_exit(start_routine_t start_routine) {

    // Declare variables
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int result;

    // Create the thread
    result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, start_routine, NULL);
    if (result != 0) {
        perror("Failed to create thread!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Return the thread id
    return thread_id;

}

bool try_lock(uint64_t* ptr) {

    // Load the current value pointed at
    uint64_t expected = *ptr;

    // While that value appears unlocked
    while ((expected & 1) == 0) {

        // If it's still unlocked, atomically set it to 1 and return success
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak(ptr, &expected, expected | 1ULL)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Otherwise update the expected value, and repeat the process
        expected = *ptr;

    }

    // If the value appears locked, return failure
    return false;

}

void unlock(uint64_t* ptr) {

    // Atomically clear the bottommost bit
    atomic_fetch_and(ptr, ~1ULL);

}

bool acquire_double_lock(uint64_t* table, int i) {

    // Try to lock table[i]
    while (!try_lock(&table[i])) {
        // Spin if lock acquisition fails
    }

    // Get the object that table[i] is pointing to
    uint64_t* pointed_obj = GET_POINTER(table[i]);

    // Try to lock it, and handle failure
    if (!try_lock(pointed_obj)) {

        // Give up! Start by unlocking table[i]
        unlock(&table[i]);

        // Then return false to indicate that we've failed to acquire the double lock
        return false;

    }

    // Return true because we successfully acquired both locks
    return true; 

}

void do_a_random_swap(uint64_t* table, int* addr_of_index_of_NULL_value) {
    
    // Get the index of the NULL value
    int index_of_NULL = *addr_of_index_of_NULL_value;

    // Choose a random index
    int i = rand() % 10;
    while (i == index_of_NULL) {
        i = rand() % 10;
    }

    // Double lock that entry, or give up if this fails
    if (!acquire_double_lock(table, i)) return;

    // Update the backpointer
    uint64_t* new_ptr = &table[index_of_NULL];
    uint64_t  old_val = *(GET_POINTER(table[i]));
    *GET_POINTER(table[i]) = MODIFY_VALUE(new_ptr, old_val);

    // Copy the item into the NULL spot and clear the old spot
    uint64_t* other_object = GET_POINTER(table[i]);
    table[index_of_NULL] = (uint64_t) other_object;
    table[i] = (uint64_t) NULL; // Note that (uint64_t) NULL == 0

    // Update the NULL index tracker
    *addr_of_index_of_NULL_value = i;

    // Unlock the other object
    unlock(other_object);

}

void* fst_start_routine(void* arg) {

    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 0) {
            do_a_random_swap(A, &index_of_NULL_value_A);
        } else {
            sleep(0.1);
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

void* snd_start_routine(void* arg) {
    
    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 0) {
            do_a_random_swap(B, &index_of_NULL_value_B);
        } else {
            sleep(0.1);
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

void* integrity_checker_start_routine(void* arg) {

    // Tell the compiler not to panic about the fact that we're not using this argument
    (void) arg;

    // Loop forever, checking the integrity of the system during odd seconds
    for (;; sleep(0.1)) {
        if (time(NULL) % 2 == 1) {
            sleep(0.1);
            verify_integrity();
            sleep(1.5);
        }
    }

    // We never get here
    return NULL;

}

int main() {

    // Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Initialize table and NULL-index trackers
    init_globals();

    // Verify integrity of the initialized values
    verify_integrity();

    // Spawn some threads
    pthread_create_or_exit(fst_start_routine);
    pthread_create_or_exit(snd_start_routine);
    pthread_create_or_exit(integrity_checker_start_routine);

    // Loop forever
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    // Return successfully (we never get here)
    return 0;

}
```